# Limits on the Use of the Indirect Object Pronoun to Indicate Possession

Tags: pronoms, verbes-pronominaux, possessif

I would like to understand why there are times when you can use the indirect object pronoun to indicate possession, and other times when you cannot. For example, you CAN say:

Je lui ai pris la main. ("I took her hand.")

but you CAN'T say:

Elle lui a vu la mère. ("She saw her mother." At least, that's what I think it should mean.)

In the second example, I believe you have to say:

Elle a vu sa mère.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Body parts and possessives

From [A Comprehensive French Grammar](https://books.google.fr/books?id=p0lZAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT130&dq=the%20definite%20article%20with%20parts%20of%20the%20body%20French%20Reference%20Grammar&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi9xtuXkoDhAhVt5eAKHSycCvoQ6AEIMTAB#v=onepage&q=the%20definite%20article%20with%20parts%20of%20the%20body%20French%20Reference%20Grammar&f=false), 228-229,
use the indirect object pronoun to refer to the person affected when the action applies to **someone else's body**.  The indirect object pronouns (complément objet indirect) are me, te, lui, nous, vous, leur.

Examples:

> Il m'a tordu le bras.  He twisted my arm. 
> Elle lui lave les cheveux.  She washes his hair. 
> Il lui a craché à la figure.  He spat in his (or her) face.

This is the same construction for your example,

> Je lui ai pris la main. I took her hand.

"I took her hand" is an action the subject applies to someone else's body and uses the COI/indirect object pronoun.

The meaning is different from the reflexive pronoun and les verbes pronominaux (me, te, se, nous, vous, se) other than that the reflexive is often used with body parts.  The underlying grammar is similar, but the reflexive is used here  when the subject and verb are referring **to the same person's body**. It functions like an indirect object in word order.

> Vous vous êtes cassé le bras.  You have broken your arm. 
> Elle s'est tourdu le bras.  She wrenched her (own) arm.

"I saw her mother" does not relate an action to a body part of another person, so you would use the possessive adjective just like in English, "J'ai vu sa mère."  To keep it simple, **no body parts**.  See section [223](https://books.google.fr/books?id=p0lZAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT130&dq=the%20definite%20article%20with%20parts%20of%20the%20body%20French%20Reference%20Grammar&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi9xtuXkoDhAhVt5eAKHSycCvoQ6AEIMTAB#v=onepage&q=possessive%20adjective&f=false).  Mon/ma/mes, ton/ta/tes, son/sa/ses, notre/nos, votre/vos, leur/leurs are the possessive adjectives.

> Ma maison 
> Ton livre 
> Son ami

Related: [Possessive adjective before a body part](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/43421/possessive-adjective-before-a-body-part)
[French possessive adjectives vs reflexive pronouns](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/22893/french-possessive-adjectives-vs-reflexive-pronouns-when-to-use-and-how)

Answer (score 3):

Your apprehension of this matter is correct.
It is the subject of a subsection in LBU 14th edition (§ 672 c)).

Here is what can be read there. (*Capital letter divisions, bold type and italics due to user LPH;
"Elles" in the first sentence stand for "les formes conjointes objet indirect des pronoms".*)

> Elles tiennent lieu d'un déterminant possessif attaché au nom
> sujet ou complément. (Comp. § 352, b,à + compl. du nom). **Il s'agit ordinairement d'un nom désignant une partie du corps** (cf. § 609, a) :
>
> **(A)**
>
> - Le cœur LUI battait (BOYLESVE, M11' Cloque, X).
> - Un grand [...] LUI tirait les
>   oreilles (COCTEAU, Enfants terribles, p, 13).
> - Son mufle énorme LUI retombait sur
>   la poitrine (FLAUB., SaL, II).
>
> **(B**) — *Même pour une partie non anatomique :*
>
> - Le destin
>   de ces hommes [.,.] LUI trottait dans l'esprit (J. D'ORMESSON, Hist. du Juif errant,
>   p. 451).
>
> **(C)** — *Cela se trouve même parfois dans des cas où le pronom devrait régulièrement avoir la forme de l'objet direct :*
>
> - Frédéric sentit quelqu'un LUI toucher à l'épaule (FLAUB., Éduc., 1,4). [L'éd. originale portait :... LE toucher.]
> - Un petit poignard ciselé LUI battait sur la cuisse gauche (ID., Mmc Bov., II, 15).
> - Aoustin [...] s'en vint LUI taper sur l'épaule (CHÂTEAUBRIANT, Brière, V).
>   (C'est un croisement de ... LUI toucher l'épaule et de... LE toucher à l'épaule.)
>
> *— Ex. plus régulier :*
>
> - Je LE frappai sur l'épaule, souriant déjà à demi (GRACQ, Rivage des Syrtes, p. 40).
>
> **(D)** *Quand le nom ne désigne pas une partie du corps, l'emploi du pronom personnel n'appartient pas au français normal :*
>
> - °Je VOUS attire l'attention que nous ne sommes pas en vacances (IONESCO, Rhinocéros, p. 64).
>   *— C'est une façon de parler très courante dans le Midi :*
> - °Le chien LUI est mort.
> - °Il S'est perdu le parapluie.
> - °[Elle] S'enlève le chapeau (H. ChARRIÈRE, Papillon, p. 474).
>   — En même temps que le possessif :
> - Je m'enlève MES pantoufles (GIONO, Roi sans divertissement, Pl.,
>   p. 569). — Voir aussi § 779, c, 2°

Notes de l'auteur

> 3. Pour ceux qui consultent le livre rapidement, j'emploie un signe de mise en garde (°) qui a parfois été mal interprété. On a cru
>    que c'est la dénonciation d'une faute (terme dont je me sers peu pourtant). Il veut simplement éviter qu'on ne croie que toutes
>    les formes et tours mentionnés sont nécessairement utilisables dans n'importe quelle circonstance,  - ce que montre le
>    commentaire ; mais encore faut-il qu'on le lise, ainsi que les considérations du § 14.

> (*passage dans section 14*)
>
> Cependant, à l'intention du lecteur pressé (ou de celui qui croit que
> tout ce qui est enregistré dans une grammaire ou un dictionnaire est par
> là légitimé, quelles que soient les circonstances), nous avons cru utile de
> signaler par un signe spécial (°) les mots ou les tours qui risqueraient de
> ne pas être compris par le destinataire de la communication ou d'être
> mal reçus par lui pour des raisons objectives. Il s'agit avant tout du type
> de communication tel qu'il a été précisé au début de ce § 14. Ce symbole
> n'est donc pas une marque d'infamie (comme disait Abel Hermant de
> la croix utilisée par Littré pour les mots absents du dict. de l'Acad.) ni
> même une sorte d'interdiction comme les panneaux routiers, mais une
> simple mise en garde, par ex. pour telle façon de parler, jugée tout à fait
> légitime par les Québécois, mais inconnue des autres francophones.

[image]

*The pronouns (source: LBU)*

Constructions on the model of "**(A)**" and "**(B)**" are standard; those in "**(C)**"  border on the unacceptable and those in "**(D)**" are really not acceptable in standard French; those in that latter section, said to be current in "Le Midi" are only current among the less educated portion of the population.

In "**(A)**" the model of the first example is not standard French. For instance, "La main gauche lui tremblait.", on this very model is not said, normally; it is found rather in the talk of people with little education. Constructions on the model of the last sentence in "**(D)**" are acceptable but not elegant (Je m'enlève mes pantoufles.).