# A very simple question concerning the verbe « barrer »

Tags: pronoms

Larousse states that one of the definitions of the verbe *barrer* is

> [Traverser une surface, être disposé en travers : L'écharpe de maire lui barrait la poitrine.](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/barrer/8116?q=se+barrer#8070)

My question is regarding the example

> L'écharpe de maire lui barrait la poitrine.

I don’t know how to articulate my question correctly as my level is still beginner but I will try my best. I’m trying to understand why **« lui »** is present. What is the pronoun **« lui »** replacing? As in if the pronoun **« lui »** wasn’t written, then what would be written instead?

If the Mayor’s name is Camille, then I’m guessing what would be written is

> L'écharpe de maire barrait la poitrine à Camille.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 2):

Yes *lui* refers to the mayor.

Your sentence is understandable but would likely be stigmatized because it looks like you translate "Camille's chest" by "*la poitrine **à** Camille*" while "*la poitrine **de** Camille*" is expected.

You can then say:

> *L'écharpe de maire barrait la poitrine de Camille.*

or just reword the original sentence that way:

> *L'écharpe de maire barrait sa poitrine.*

See also:

[Limits on the Use of the Indirect Object Pronoun to Indicate Possession](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/43679/limits-on-the-use-of-the-indirect-object-pronoun-to-indicate-possession)

[Possessive adjective before a body part](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/43421/possessive-adjective-before-a-body-part)

[French possessive adjectives vs reflexive pronouns (when to use and how)](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/22893/french-possessive-adjectives-vs-reflexive-pronouns-when-to-use-and-how)

Comment: Thank you so much @jlliagre for your help. 

Answer (score 1):

Usually, *lui* replace a "complément d'objet indirect" so yes it is replacing *maire*. It could be also formulated as *L'écharpe de maire barrait sa poitrine* without going through 'lui', but that would be vague without any other explanation about the person whom the *écharpe* is barring the chest.

Comment: I agree that the "SA poitrine" version would be vague but to the extent that "écharpe de maire" can be a general way of referring to the tricolor sash that any/all French mayors wear on occasion, couldn't the original "lui" version also be vague, with "lui" referring to whomever is wearing the sash, whether they're a/the mayor or not?  The vagueness I see with BOTH versions might disappear if it had been "écharpe DU maire" & not "écharpe DE maire" but maybe I'm wrong about "écharpe de maire" possibly being a 3-word way to specify what kind of sash it is and not necessarily who is wearing it.